# Figure captions: one above and one below, both numbered the same

Tags: floats, captions

I have a figure with two captions, one above the figure (headline) and one below (explanation). That is fine, but now I want the below caption to repeat the figure number from the headline.

This is what I have:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Headline}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Graphic1}
\caption*{Explanation}
\end{figure}
```

So how can I include a figure-count in the below caption as well?

Comment: just use `\thefigure` in your explanation at the point you want the number

Answer (score 1):

I would set up the environment as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Headline} \label{fig:headline}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Graphic1}
\smallskip
Explanation and legend, involving a cross-reference 
to Figure \ref{fig:headline} itself.
\end{figure}
```